# Android add text (timestamp) to recordered video

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Is there any way to add text (e.g. date+time) to recorded by Android camera video?
For video recording I'm using standard pair of classes: `Camera` and `MediaRecorder`.

What I'm looking for is shown on this screen:

[image]

Any ideas please?

Comment: have you find any solution in this..

Comment: I've decided to store information in the separate text file

Comment: You might be interested in an approach using MediaRecorder and mobile-ffmpeg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65505434/361413).